# qtchoose doesn't run due to "'/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qtchooser': No such file or directory" error

Tags: 12.10, application-development, qt5

When I try to start qtchooser i get this notification:

```
qtchooser: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qtchooser': No such file or directory
```

I've installed Qt5 from [ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-beta-proper](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-qt5-edgers/+archive/qt5-beta-proper/+packages)
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Oh, sorry I've forgotten to mention that. I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: What is the output of `which qtchooser`?

Comment: The output is `/usr/bin/qtchoser`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is normal, although uninformative. In essence you're trying to execute `qtchooser` with itself, which doesn't work. Run the `man qtchooser` command on a terminal for how to use qtchooser, or just keep the ubuntu-sdk (and qt5-default) packages installed, in which case you don't need to care about qtchooser existing.

Upstream has fixed the problem with a more helpful text nowadays, but that version of qtchooser is not yet in Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay, I thought whith qtchooser I could set qt4 as default because FindQt4.cmake throws an error when it finds qt5 qmake. But thank you for your help. Now I know how to use it. :)